FullCalendar Events from a Function
I am trying the following code to get FullCalendar events from an existing array
events: function(start, end, callback) {
  var events = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < calendarCount; i++) {
    events.push({
      title: calendarObject[i].title,
      start: new Date(calendarObject[i].startDate * 1000),
      end: new Date(calendarObject[i].endDate * 1000),
      allDay: calendarObject[i].isAllDay,
      color: calendarObject[i].color
    });
  }
  console.log(events)
  callback(events);
}

The events array succesfully prints out in the console.  But FullCalendar spits out the following error message:

Among other variations found, I have also tried this...
for (var i = 0; i < calendarCount; i++) {
  var buildingEvents = $.map(calendarObject, function(item) {
    return {
      title: calendarObject[i].title,
      start: new Date(calendarObject[i].startDate * 1000),
      end: new Date(calendarObject[i].endDate * 1000),
      allDay: calendarObject[i].isAllDay,
      color: calendarObject[i].color
    };
  });
}

...and then just events: buildingEvents
That did not spit out any errors in console but the calendar had no events.

Why do you think that's an error message? It's an array with 20 objects in it.

Just before the array.  It has an 'undefined'.

I don't understand that output, you have two log messages on the same line. I've never seen that before. But you only have one console.log() call in the posted code. One of them must be coming from somewhere else.

And undefined is not an error message, it's the value of a variable being logged.

Solved with this code...
var events = [];
for (var i=0; i < calendarCount; i++) {
           
            events.push({
            title: calendarObject[i].title,
            start: new Date(calendarObject[i].startDate * 1000),
            end: new Date(calendarObject[i].endDate * 1000),
            allDay: calendarObject[i].isAllDay,
            color: calendarObject[i].color
            }); 

}

and then 'events: events' in the calendar setup
